# Validating missing mandatory columns in pandas read_csv command

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am reading a csv file using [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). How to detect if the mandatory columns are empty?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. You'd still have a header, but no value under it?

Comment: Please add some details about what you have tested for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can test each column:

```
 any(df[col].isnull())
 all(df[col].isnull())
```